# What symbols match which personality types?

Tags: furistas-cat-cafe

Often a daily task will ask me to match people with cats of a certain personality type (friendly, playful etc). The problem is, they give the me task in words, but the customers/cats show them as little icons. Some I can kinda tell what they should be but I have trouble with knowing the actual intended personality type with some of the icons.

What personality type does each icon represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image shows what I’ve learned so far
[image]